# How to validate bitbucket repository with GitHub repository after migration done

Tags: github, salesforce, bitbucket

How to validate bitbucket repository with GitHub repository after migration done?

I have migrated repository and branches from bitbucket to GitHub repository.
How can I compare/test these two repositories or how can check whether it's migrated properly or not?

Is there any automated way to validate or test the migrated content?

Comment: How does this question relate to `salesforce`?